# How do I execute an array of promises synchronously with delay

Tags: asynchronous, promise, delay

I have an array of JSON objects. I want to iterate through the array, and for each object check some parameters, and if certain conditions are true, make a request to create a record using the [Air-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airtable) module.

Because of the rate limit, I want to throttle how quickly i make those requests, essentially calling the functions in series, and also implementing a delay in between them.

Promises have always confused the crap out of me. How would Iterate over an array to achieve this with promises. Can I do this with Async Await? I know that some promise libraries like Bluebird have both a delay and a concurrent function, but I am pretty confused about how to use them correctly.

Comment: A loop with `async`/`await` will probably be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through array synchronously you can use `for ... of` construction:

```
async function doSomethingWithArray(array, delayTime) {
  for (const item of array) {
    await someMethod(item);
    await delay(delayTime);
  }
}
```

the simplest delay function is:

```
function delay(delayTime) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayTime));
}
```